# In my model class normaly working but it show error now iam working i don't know what is the reason

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

[image]

as you see in this picture it shows error when iam using this model class how to solve this problem.

I tried but it's not working.

Comment: could you include your class model code too?

Comment: also what do you see when you hover on one of those line that has red line under them?

Comment: i included and i hover the red line nothing is showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `Map`'s key/value pairs are linked with a `:` not a `=`, so in your code instead of doing this:

```
key = value,
```

change it to this:

```
key: value,
```

and the same thing for your `class`.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong syntax, replace all of yours `=` with `:` will solve problem